# Does Ubuntu 12.04 support the Intel H65M chipset/Celeron B800 CPU? 

Tags: intel-graphics, intel

I'm gonna buy a laptop I want to install ubuntu on it.

Samsung // Model: NP300E4Z-A04CL // Processor: [Intel Celeron B800 1,5 GHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/59570/Intel-Celeron-Processor-B800-%282M-Cache-1_50-GHz%29) // Cores: 2 // Chipset: [H65M](http://ark.intel.com/products/chipsets/52774) // 2GB DDR3 // Video: Intel HD Graphics, integrated // WiFi: 802.11bgn

I've been searching for hours to know if everything will work! But I can't find anything about Ubuntu 12.04 running in it... 
I just want a fast system for my office work, skype, external screens...

Any benchmark or experience about if this laptop will work fine under Ubuntu 12.04 would be highly apreciated !!

Comment: Finally buyed it and... It works like a charm!! I'm experiencing an ultra-fast system, no heating problems, no software problems... no problem at all!! Thanks IZX for helping me in this very good decision! PS: For everybody out there searching for a cheap but performant laptop for running ubuntu, I recomment to them this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Edit: Jean-Pierre has confirmed that the laptop idea indeed work well with Ubuntu 12.04.

Yes, the laptop should *probably* work very well with Ubuntu 12.04.

- The Sandy Bridge chipset (H65M) is compatible.
- The CPU has internal Intel HD Graphics, which work great with Ubuntu without needing to install any extra drivers, etc.
- The brand of wireless card is not known, but if it is a Broadcom card, you may have to install extra drivers provided by Ubuntu to make it work. It's a good idea to have access to a wired connection (ethernet) for this step.

Comment: Thanks!! I was not sure at all but had a good feeling about it. I will tell you how it worked once I have the laptop.

Comment: @Jean-PierreVidal: please consider re-accepting this answer; I have added the updated information from your comment to it. Thanks!